# Has Ash ever appeared on any Pokémon TCG cards?

Tags: pokemon

Ash Ketchum is the star of the Pokémon anime. Has he ever appeared on any TCG cards to date? I know the cards tend to follow the game universe, but I'm wondering if over the 20+ years the lines blurred at some point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Pokémon TCG follows the console games rather than anime, Ash was never a star in the TCG (because he was never in any console game). However, to commemorate few films in Generations III and IV, few promotional cards depicting Ash's Pokémon were released (along many other Owner's Pokémon originating from the films), although all are Japan-exclusive. No Trainer card named just *Ash* exists.

- *Pokémon: Destiny Deoxys* (M07)

  - [Ash's Torkoal](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Torkoal_(Movie_VS_Pack_9))
- inserted in a children magazine

  - [Ash's Treecko](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Treecko_(ADV-P_Promo_36))
- *Pokémon: Lucario and the Mystery of Mew* (M08)

  - [Ash's Grovyle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Grovyle_(Movie_VS_Pack_1))
  - [Ash's Phanpy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Phanpy_(Movie_VS_Pack_4))
  - [Ash's Swellow](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Swellow_(Movie_VS_Pack_7))
- *Pokémon Ranger and the Temple of the Sea* (M09)

  - [Ash's Aipom](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Aipom_(Movie_VS_Pack_10))
- *Pokémon: Arceus and the Jewel of Life* (M12)

  - [Pikachu [image: M]](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pikachu_M_(Movie_Random_Pack_Promo_12))
  - [Pikachu [image: M] LV.X](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pikachu_M_LV.X_(DPt-P_Promo_43))
  - [Staraptor [image: M]](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Staraptor_M_(Movie_Random_Pack_Promo_18))

As @JonathanJ mentioned in comments, there is also a card named [Ash-Greninja [image: EX]](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash-Greninja-EX_(XY_Promo_133)) depicting a Bond Phenomenon Greninja originating in Gen 6 anime. It was released in both Japanese and English, but only the [second Japanese print](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:XYZ_Character_Song_Project_2_Limited_B.png) features a picture of Ash.

As @Thunderforge mentioned in comments, in April 2017 a new Japanese-exclusive subset named *Ash vs Team Rocket Deck Kit* was released, based on Alolan episodes of anime. Some artworks of Pokémon that Ash owns also depict himself. The subset also includes the first Trainer card with *Ash* in its name.

- [Rowlet](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rowlet_(Ash_vs_Team_Rocket_Deck_1))
- [Ash's Pikachu [image: GX]](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Pikachu-GX_(Ash_vs_Team_Rocket_Deck_5))
- [Tauros](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tauros_(Ash_vs_Team_Rocket_Deck_14))
- [Ash's Friendship](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Friendship_(Ash_vs_Team_Rocket_Deck_25))

Comment: Also on Ash-Greninja-EX (similar to the other Ash's pokemon) if you want to add it: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:XYZ_Character_Song_Project_2_Limited_B.png Interestingly, it was a legal English card although only the Japanese version has the Ash insert - Greninja apparently takes on Ash's characteristics :)

Comment: As per my other comment, English card - Ash-Greninja-EX = http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash-Greninja-EX_(XY_Promo_133)